# Finite Sylow subgroups of periodic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, p-groups

Let $G$ be a (possibly infinite) periodic group, and suppose that $G$ admits a maximal finite $p$-subgroup $P$. By this I mean that we do not assume that $P$ is not strictly contained in any other $p$-subgroup of $G$, but that it is not contained in any other *finite* $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Does it follow that all maximal finite $p$-subgroups of $G$ are conjugate? If not, what are some reasonable assumptions one might add for this to hold?

Comment: It's not true in general - I believe that there are Tarski monsters in which not all subgroups of order $p$ are conjugate (there are also examples in which they are). The result holds in locally finite groups.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it is true at least for amenable groups?